# Choosing Appropriate Bit Length

Tags: verilog

So, this has been bothering me for a couple semesters, and I guess I'm just too embarrassed to ask the professor for clarification, but I always feel a little in the dark about "choosing appropriate bit length" for output of binary arithmetic.

Say, for instance I am using verilog to code an adder that adds 3 10-bit 2's complement numbers, and will need to output a one-bit overflow detector.  Should I choose the output to be 10-bit?  Or should I increase it to 11 bit to avoid overflow for convenience?

I have no specific code as it's just a conceptual question.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean bit *width*... You choose it in a such way that it will produce the output you need. It really depends on what you are expecting from it.

Comment: Never be afraid to ask, but including the overflow preserves accuracy.

Comment: Is your result also 2's complement? Will \$1FF_h + 1FF_h + 1FF_h\$ fit without corrupting the top sign bit ?

Comment: This isn't an embarrassing question, it's actually a quite good question. However, you do need to tell the computer somehow that it's not capable of adding such numbers. Say you were designing that chip in a hardware description language, how can you design that?

Comment: @glen_geek, yes it is.  And ah, interesting. I think I understand what you're asking there.

Comment: In the end, it depends on what you are doing. If you are implementing an algorithm, then you have to look at it and figure out what is done with the high order bits. If they are never used, you can discard them. But if it is essential to preserve the actual sum of the two inputs, then you need to keep the overflow store in a larger register. Also, if the numbers are signed, then you have to look at what happens to the sign information.

Answer (score 1):

If you adds two 10-bit 2's complement numbers, you need 11 bit to display all possible results. If you add three such words, you will need 12 bits. You may use only the 10 most significant bits of the result but you will loose precision.

If you know that all inputs are restricted to -170 < x < 170, 10 bits will be enough to hold all possible results.

If you use a 10 bit output plus a overflow signal, you do know the result is bigger than 511, but you don't know if it is larger or smaller than 1023.

I would like a solution that does not deliver false results without an error indication.